# Issues with tkinter canvas & matplotlib figure resizing

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Relatively new to tkinter and I am now stuck. I am building an application where the user is loading csv files with data. This is stored as DataFrames. The purpose of the app is to be able to plot the data that has been loaded. All is good until I started implementing the option of adding additional axis to the plot. Currently, I am only adding the option of adding a y-axis. All is fine, and I am able to plot the data, but here is where the issues start.

For plotting, I am using the FigureCanvasTkAgg implementation. I have a canvas that is created and the plot is drawn onto this. However, I am experiencing that the figure changes size such that the right axis is outside of the window. Increasing the size of the window reveals the axis. I have implemented a resizing of the figure binding the canvas to an event where the new size is picked up. However, the resizing is living its own life. I have recreated the a similar set-up with the parasite axis examples found in matplotlib.
Can someone please explain why the figure is behaving as it does when changing the window size?

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA

def resize_canvas(event):
    
    print(event)
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height
    print(new_width, new_height)
        
    plot_window.get_tk_widget().configure(width=new_width, height=new_height)
        
    fig.set_figheight(new_height/96)
    fig.set_figwidth(new_width/96)
    
    plot_window.draw()
    
root = tk.Tk()

main_fr = tk.Frame()

main_fr.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

root.wm_geometry("736x670")
root.minsize(736,670)
root.maxsize(1600,800)

fig = Figure(figsize=(736/96,670/96), tight_layout=True, dpi=96)
plot_window = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=main_fr)


host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes, figure=fig)
        
par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()


offset = 50
new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",
                            axes=par2,
                        offset=(offset, 0))

par1.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)
par2.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)

host.set_xlim(0, 2)
host.set_ylim(0, 2)

host.set_xlabel("Distance")
host.set_ylabel("Density")
par1.set_ylabel("Temperature")
par2.set_ylabel("Velocity")

p1, = host.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], label="Density")
p2, = par1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2], label="Temperature")
p3, = par2.plot([0, 1, 2], [50, 30, 15], label="Velocity")

par1.set_ylim(0, 4)
par2.set_ylim(1, 65)

host.legend()

host.axis["left"].label.set_color(p1.get_color())
par1.axis["right"].label.set_color("red")
par2.axis["right"].label.set_color(p3.get_color())  

main_fr.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
main_fr.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)

plot_window.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")        
plot_window.get_tk_widget().bind('<Configure>', resize_canvas)
#plot_window.draw()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: have you checked [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68600178/12446721). Your problem solved? if yes try to mark this answer as accepted answer else if any error provide error or any queries ask in comment.

Comment: The problem is that the original code is part of a larger app. Removing the main_fr not possible. Root contains several blocks - navigation buttons and container where new "pages" are displayed. One page has the plotting feature. User is allowed make cross plot. New series can be added either on existing or new y-axis (hence the parasite option). When second y-axis (either left or right) is added, det plot shrinks slightly with each new series added.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve :

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
    
root = tk.Tk()

fig = Figure(figsize=(10,7), dpi=96)
plot_window = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)

host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes, figure=fig)
        
par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()


offset = 50
new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",axes=par2,offset=(offset, 0))

par1.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)
par2.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)

host.set_xlim(0, 2)
host.set_ylim(0, 2)

host.set_xlabel("Distance")
host.set_ylabel("Density")
par1.set_ylabel("Temperature")
par2.set_ylabel("Velocity")

p1, = host.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], label="Density")
p2, = par1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2], label="Temperature")
p3, = par2.plot([0, 1, 2], [50, 30, 15], label="Velocity")

par1.set_ylim(0, 4)
par2.set_ylim(1, 65)

host.legend()

host.axis["left"].label.set_color(p1.get_color())
par1.axis["right"].label.set_color("red")
par2.axis["right"].label.set_color(p3.get_color())  

plot_window.get_tk_widget().pack(side = tk.TOP, expand = True , fill = tk.BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

I have removed that `main_fr` and pack that `FigureCanvasTkAgg` in root, and that `tight_layout` is causing problem.